# Inno Setup correctly position a label with respect to screen DPI

Tags: inno-setup, dpi

I am trying to position a label above the `InfoAfterPage` section and have it always appear there no matter what scaling is used, just as the amount of space required shown below is positioned.

[image: Label Position]

I am using `Label.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height - 20`, but am aware that may appear out of place if the screen is scaled in any way. What is the best way to set this so that always stays in this position no matter how the screen is scaled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`ScaleY` support function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_scaley):

```pascal
Label.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height - ScaleY(20);
```

Or even better, do not even make assumptions about the label height:

```pascal
Label.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height - ScaleY(7) - Label.Height;
```

---

Or for your specific case, just reuse a position of the `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel`:

```pascal
Label.Top := WizardForm.ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel.Top;
```

Note that the `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel` exists for a lifetime of the wizard, so you can access it anytime.

Comment: I have used the `Label.Top := WizardForm.InfoAfterPage.Height - ScaleY(7) - Label.Height;` method, as it is on a custom page and the `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel` will not exist on that page. The screenshot was just to show how I wanted to position it. Many thanks.

Comment: The `ComponentsDiskSpaceLabel` exists for the lifetime of the wizard, so it does not matter.